# Show the equivalency between the two expected values?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative integers. They are random variables.

Show that $E[X]=\sum_{n>o} P[X\geqslant n]$
Show also that $E[X*Y]=\sum_{n=1}^{\inf}\sum_{m=1}^{\inf}P[(X\geqslant n) \cap
(Y \geqslant m)]$

I am having trouble because I thought these were just the formal definitions of the expectation.

EDIT:
$E[X]=\sum n*P[X=n]$
$=(P[X=1]+P[X=2]+P[X=3]+\dots)+(P[X=2]+P[X=1])+P[X=1]$
$=\sum_{n=1}P[X=n]+\sum_{n=2}P[X=n]+\sum_{n=3}P[X=n]+\dots$
$=P[X>0]+P[X>1]+P[X>2]+\dots$
$=\sum_{n>0}P[X \geqslant n]$

Here is my attempt for the first equivalency. I think that makes sense, and it's what I wish to show. Can someone confirm?

For the second, I'm starting with the definition that

$E[XY]=Cov(X,Y)+E[X]E[Y]$, but I'm not sure how this will turn into the right hand of the expression.

Comment: What did you mean by "formal definition" of the expectation (I'm from Mexico and, curiosity, the english expression "formal argument", "formal theorem", "formal etc..." means, in spanish, the opposite)

Comment: The one-dimensional case has been explained countlessly many times on the site (see the "Related" pages on the right-hand-side column, to begin with). For the two-dimensional case, copy the neatest method of the one-dimensional case, that is, use the pointwise identity $$XY=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant n,Y\geqslant m}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are not the formal definitions of expectation.

The formal definition is:  $\mathsf E(X) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n\,\mathsf P(X=n)$

You've been asked to show: $\mathsf E(X) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \mathsf P(X\geq n)$

Can you see the difference?  Can you make an attempt?

**Hint**: $\; n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n 1\;$ and $\;\mathsf P(X\geq k) = \sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty \mathsf P(X=k)$

Comment: Yes, actually the first one makes sense to me now!